# How can I use .capitalize inside a rails 3 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The `.capitalize!` function doesn't seem to work inside a model in Rails.

Is there a way around this? I have a valid business case for using this in a model by the way.

**Here's the code that's throwing me an error:**

```
def something
    ...
    str.strip
    str.capitalize!
end
```

Error I get is `can't convert nil into String`

Everything works find if I remove the last line.

**Edit:** Sorry, I had a brain fart! Fixed it.

Comment: Could you post some more code, because `capitalize` is a method on `String`, so it is basically available on any string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with writing just
`"string".capitalize!` ?

It's just a ruby String method, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21

upd

and as it's obvious now, the problem was the string you were trying to update was nil

Answer (score 1):

Error I get is can't convert nil into String

it means your str object of string class is nil so you are not able to perform this action so you can use debugger 
like 
def something
    ...
    str.strip

    str.capitalize!
end

and go to terminal and try to find that is str having some proper value related to string class or its null or having some other object value

and one more thing 
if u use
str.capitalize!

means it will check is that string having first character capital or not and according to that you will get answer